# How to auto-respond to fsck prompt at boot

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems

I have an ubuntu server (11.10) on a single-board computer that occasionally is subject to being powered down unexpectedly.  When it is booted afterward, fsck prompts the user to hit 'f' to check the drive.  Because this server does not normally have a monitor and keyboard connected, and the only way to normally access it is through SSH, this is very inconvenient.

Is there a way of guaranteeing that on boot any required fsck check can be done without user input?  Basically, I want it to always run 'fsck -y' on boot (when problems are detected), rather than prompting the user for input.

Thanks!

Comment: -a : Automatically repair the file system without any questions (use this option with caution). Note that e2fsck(8) supports -a for backwards compatibility only. This option is mapped to e2fsck's -p option which is safe to use, unlike the -a option that most file system checkers support.

Comment: Where do I add that -a option?  I'm not running fsck myself, the ubuntu server runs it on boot automatically.

Comment: The unbuntu server will simply be running one of the init.d scripts. My unbuntu VM is off atm, but you can find which startup script is running the fsck and add the option

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I found two related solutions to my problem:

I'm not sure these are valid everywhere, but they work on ubuntu server 11.10.

/etc/default/rcS looks like this:

```
#
# /etc/default/rcS
#
# Default settings for the scripts in /etc/rcS.d/
#
# For information about these variables see the rcS(5) manual page.
#
# This file belongs to the "initscripts" package.

# delete files in /tmp during boot older than x days.
# '0' means always, -1 or 'infinite' disables the feature
TMPTIME=0

# spawn sulogin during boot, continue normal boot if not used in 30 seconds
SULOGIN=no

# do not allow users to log in until the boot has completed
DELAYLOGIN=no

# assume that the BIOS clock is set to UTC time (recommended)
UTC=yes

# be more verbose during the boot process
VERBOSE=no

# automatically repair filesystems with inconsistencies during boot
FSCKFIX=no
```

Make sure that that final line instead reads

```
# automatically repair filesystems with inconsistencies during boot
FSCKFIX=yes
```

Another barrier I had to the system just booting always without requiring user intervention was the grub bootloader screen waiting for user input after a failed / interrupted boot.

This requires editing the grub setup file in 
/etc/grub.d/00_header

```
/etc/grub.d$ grep -r -n -C3 timeout ./
./00_header-229-    fi
./00_header-230-fi
./00_header-231-
./00_header:232:make_timeout ()
./00_header-233-{
./00_header-234-    cat << EOF
./00_header-235-if [ "\${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
./00_header:236:  set timeout=-1
./00_header-237-else
./00_header:238:  set timeout=${2}
./00_header-239-fi
./00_header-240-EOF
./00_header-241-}
```

simply change line 236 to

```
set timeout = 0
```

and line 238 to

```
set timeout = 0
```

This causes the system to never pause while booting.  After editing the file, run
    `sudo update-grub`
to get the changes implemented in the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file.

Answer (score 4):

For grub, instead of tinkering with the file as above, and if you are using the latest version of GRUB which is grub2, the cleaner way would be to:

Change "/etc/default/grub"
    Add line `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT="30"`
    Then run `update-grub`

Answer (score 1):

[Senthil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24854863/3178743) answer about [RECORFAIL TIMETOUT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202309/cannot-get-grub-menu-to-timeout-or-go-away) directive is related to Grub bootloader and occurs after a *"failed boot attempt"* as stated [here](https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Grub2_recordfail/en). Despite being related to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9932250/3178743), and one point to be observed on forced reboots, it's not the answer to the fsck problem (*"always run 'fsck -y'"*).

I believe [Nato Saichek answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10077813/3178743) is on the right way. [This link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-force-fsck-on-the-next-reboot-or-boot-sequence/) aproaches the problem of forcing fsck in Ubuntu and RHEL/CentOS. In the case of Ubuntu, the scripts get some options from `/etc/default/rcS`. So I believe uncommenting and changing the default `#FSCKFIX=no` to `FSCKFIX=yes` would be sufficient.